# People Search Results Links to /person.aspx?accountname=DOMAIN/USERNAME Causes 404 User Not Found

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, search-results, people-search

When doing people searches in SharePoint 2010 Server, the account name is formatted DOMAIN/USERNAME instead of DOMAIN\USERNAME. This is causing a User Not Found error when trying to click on their profile link. Has anyone run into this? I've been hunting for a setting in CA, on the site, in search, in user profiles that controls this but can't find one that has fixed the issue. I verified the user profile actually lists the AccountName attribute as DOMAIN\USERNAME.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.stackexchange.com! I see this is your first contribution to the site. I think it would be appropriate to move your update to an answer. That will make it more clear for others who encounter this problem in the future that this is an answered question.

Comment: Yep, please add your findings as answer. You will have to wait a bit before you can mark as answer though due to the way this site works :)

Answer (score 2):

*Moved answer from question:*

I found that the AccountName property for the user profile had the 'index' checkbox unselected. Selected this and reran a full crawl for the user profiles and this updated the search results with the correct link to the user profile.